# How to access state scoped to current behaviour from postStop

Tags: functional-programming, akka, actor

I have an online game, with an actor that represents a user's state. State updates via recursive `become` calls:

```
private PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> updatedUser(final User user) {
    return ReceiveBuilder.
        ...
        matchEquals("update", s -> {
            context().become(updatedUser(new User(...)));
        }).build();
}
```

Now when the user leaves the game (actor stops), I need to save its state to a database. I think the ideal place for this would be sending a message from `postStop`. But user's state is out of scope.

```
public void postStop() throws Exception {
    //user state out of scope
    Database.tell(user, self());

}
```

I don't want to have state as an actor field. What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to access the `user` value outside of the `updatedUser` function.

Just make your user state an instance variable of the actor.